# What is missing out of my code that it cannot download the content but codes?

Tags: download, export-to-csv

I have a table with the following variable data headings: Title, URI, Meta description, Main heading, Body text.

I want to fetch these array of data and present them in a csv file as soon as I hit the download button.

The function I have is not working, it keep download the raw code of the page instead of the input parameters from the form.

```
    var onpage = "Title, URI, Meta description, Main heading, Body text\n";
    keyArray.forEach(function(row){
        onpage += row.join(", ");
        onpage += "\n";
    });
    console.log(onpage);
    downloadContent.href = "data:text/csv;charset-utf=8," + encodeURI(onpage);
    downloadContent.target = "_blank";
    downloadContent.download = "file.csv";
    downloadContent.click();
 }
```

Comment: Good day guys, please, help me to resolve the issue above. I really need to implement this as soon as possible. I need the code to work and pull the actual data into csv and not pulling the page raw codes to csv. Many thanks.